# Should I add interfaces for my simple game classes?

Tags: interface, uml, game-development, class-diagram, class-design

I'am trying to create an UML class diagram for a simple game. I've three inheritance classes (`NPC`, `Player`, `Monster`) and they should interact with each other (e.g. in an attack).

I wonder if I should use interfaces in my simple case. Also how can I expand my diagramm?

[image: uml diagramm]

Comment: Hello Illya.  I've edited your question to highlight your question about interfaces.  Because otherwise it would be too broad.  I hope it's ok for you.  By the way,  in the text you mention "NPC". I guess this is Non-Player Character.  In your diagram, you mention no NPC but NPS.  Is it a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class `Character` is specialized into: `NPC` (Non-Player Character), `Player` and `Monster` and you wonder if you'd need an interface:

- As a `Monster` seems to be a non-player character, it should probably inherit from `NPC` instead of `Character`
- As a human player really ***is not*** a character but just happen to be  represented by a character in the game, it could be interesting to separate the responsibilities of the `Player` and the corresponding `Character`.  So you'd have a simple association between the two and not an inheritance. An immediate advantage, is that the player could chose the preferred character to impersonate him/her.
- A [mediator](https://www.oodesign.com/mediator-pattern.html) could be used to manage the interaction between the all the characters in the game. You could create a `Colleague` interface, and let different classes implement this interface.  But if your `Colleagues` are necessarily all `Characters`,  you could just rely on the superclass as you did.

More generally, an additional interface is a proven approach if you want to decouple classes.  You should definitively consider them if you'd develop a game engine that is to be reused in a lot of different games: you'd then have an engine that relies only interfaces that are independent of any specific game.  Each game would then pick the relevant classes to implement the interfaces.  But for your specific case, it seems to be an overkill.

This being said,  the main challenge you'll be confronted with is that you'll end up with deep class hierarchies that'll be difficult to evolve.  This is why, the game industry prefers the [entity-component-system pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) that prefer composition over inheritance. But this is a different story, and there are full books on that topic ;-)